# Shazamcrest custom matching with collections

Tags: java, hamcrest

With [Shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) is is possible to do custom matching by supplying a field path and a matcher that is then applied to that field.

For example[[cf]](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest#custom-matching):

```java
assertThat(
  actualPerson,
  sameBeanAs(expectedPerson).with("address.streetName", startsWith("Via"));
```

How do you do the same if you are matching collections? Can you apply a custom matcher to each object in the collection? To all objects in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Shazamcrest matchers work just like regular Hamcrest matchers, you should be able to use them with all of the built-in collection matchers.

```
assertThat(
  people,
  contains(
    sameBeanAs(expectedPerson).with("address.streetName", startsWith("Via")
  )
);
```

The documentation says that you must use a custom `assertThat` from the package. While that's only for the failure descriptions, it may interfere with using some matchers.